# Verify that the six matrices form the group

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I solved the problem myself and I want to check if my solution is legitimate.
My solution usually has partial errors or is not solid enough.
Thank you!

---

Verify that the six matrices $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ from a group under matrix multiplication. [*Hint*: Don't try to compute all products of these matrices. Instead, think how the column vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ is transformed by multiplying it on the left by each of the matrices.]

What group discussed in this section is isomorphic to this group of six matrices?

---

Comment: Note that the product of a matrix and a vector should be a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: Note that $
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
1&0&0
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
2 \\
3
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
2 \\
3 \\
1
\end{array}\right],
$
not $
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&2&0 \\
0&0&3 \\
1&0&0
\end{array}\right].
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sigma=(12)$ and $\tau=(123)$ generate $S_3$, so that it is enough to consider the map $\phi\colon S_3\rightarrow G$, given by $\phi(\sigma)=A_6$ and $\phi(\tau)=A_3$, where $A_1,\ldots ,A_6$ are the six given matrices. Then $\phi$ is an isomorphism. See also
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S3.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the six matrices are all six permutations of the three rows of $I_3$. The group represented here is $S_3$, $|S_3|=3!=6$, so no computation is necessary.